PPAs do not have release files
I have noticed, that when I try to sudo apt update, the terminal keeps showing me errors that I had when I was trying to install something else time ago.
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease            
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease               
Get:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease [3,632 B]
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease         
Ign:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease
Ign:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:13 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/vala-team/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:15 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease
Err:16 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Err:17 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Err:18 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/vala-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key 008940D610E4CD892340AB0A4CE987B57DAAC99C uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

How do I get rid of them?

The GNOME3 Team PPA's have been EOL'ed. The Flatpak one you may need to remove manually from your .sources file and install properly per my Answer.

PPAs or Personal Package Archives do not get security checks, so the only checks are those you perform yourself.  Did you perform any?  as an unsupported/unmaintained PPA if added to your system, should have been detected BEFORE adding it, thus I'll suggest re-evaluating how you perform security checks for Personal Package Archive or 3rd party sources without any guarantees.

End Of Life
Quoting the link from my comment:

=== End of Life ===
This PPA is no longer updated for releases older than Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. If you are using an older release, please ppa-purge this PPA and consider upgrading to a newer Ubuntu release.
Unless otherwise posted, updates will only be provided in this PPA for 7 months from the original release of the associated Ubuntu series.
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-gnome/2017-March/004229.html

We can safely remove it like so (note that ppa-purge may also work, but I know apt is guaranteed to be installed):
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
We can repeat the removal for GNOME 3 Staging also, as a similar EOL notice is posted there also:
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
We then repeat the same for the Flatpak PPA
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:flatpak/stable
I'm going to assume the OP isn't on a LTS release and that if the above removal fails for the Flatpak PPA that it will need to be manually removed from the .sources file(s) and readded properly using the link I provided.

Thank you, that resolved my problem

@LePulga Glad I could help.  Pro-Tip: If a link/tutorial/article etc on a website recommends that you install a PPA, always Google/Search for the PPA name before adding it and look for the official PPA homepage in the form: https://launchpad.net/~<ppa-name>/os/branch-or-version  In this case OS will always read as ubuntu.  If this was correct, don't forget to tick the checkmark, and welcome to AskUbuntu!
